# I need to replace all the characters of string in python

Tags: python

I need to replace the characters by scanning the string completely. Is regex helpful for this?

```
Input: AAAGCCTT 
Output: TTTCGGAA.
```

I have tried using `replace` but i don't find it helpful.

Comment: No, I think she wants to reverse the string but replacing the characters according to the original ones as mentioned in the example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```
import string
print('AAAGCCTT'.translate(string.maketrans('AGCT','TCGA')))
```

out:

```
TTTCGGAA
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python3 you don't even need to import the string module

```
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Oct  9 2013, 14:50:09) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('AAAGCCTT'.translate(str.maketrans('AGCT','TCGA')))
TTTCGGAA
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a function like this:

```
from string import maketrans
trans_table = maketrans('ACGT','TGCA')

def trans(s):
    return s.translate(trans_table)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
>>> trans('AAAGCCTT')
'TTTCGGAA'
```